# posting a special command on an ember model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember-data model called session.
The API server (cannot change it) doesn't support POST command to update the entire model (so I can't just call `.save()`

I want to be able to change a property called `editedStatus`.
The way the API server is allowing me to do it is by:
`<address>/edit_session_status?...`
The rest of the properties are de-facto read only (from ember that is).
How can I acheive that. Can I somehow override `.save()` and do a POST request only for this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override updateRecord and createRecord (for new sessions) method in your adapter:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_createRecord
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_updateRecord

Furthermore you could skip serializing all other attributes using a serializer:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_attrs (look for "{serialize: false}")

For your adapter and serializer you can use the application adapter/serializer or a model specific session adapter/serializer (serializers/session.js, adapters/session.js).